# Do i have to disable magic quotes when using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sql-injection, magic-quotes

Simple question and i want simple answer. 
I'm using PDO prepared statements to make sure my data are safely processed to the database.
But im confused. Do i have to disable magic quotes or use stripslashes on variables if magic_quotes are enabled. And after then letting the PDO do the security job ?

Comment: Yes, this is trivially true because one should *always* disable magic quotes.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using PDO's prepared statements to insert data into your database, the data will go into the database exactly as you insert it.  `magic_quotes` adds slashes to the data: these will therefore be present in the database. This is obviously not what you want.

As you say, disable magic quotes or, if necessary, use `stripslashes`.

Comment: So i have to use stripslashes and then let the pdo prepared statements do the security job ?

Comment: PDO prepared statements (if used correctly) will prevent SQL injection, yes. There's more to "security" than just preventing SQL injection, however...

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know that more thingy i have to learn.
Can you recommend a good book about php security.
I know those null bytes sql injection XSS session hijacking etc
Are you saying there is much more. So far my code is clean
I use object oriented programming. Everything is in classess and objects. But im still scared. Security is important

Comment: I'm just saying that all PDO prepared statements will do is protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Stage1 - View:

You type **somebody's name** to `<input type="text" name="name"></input>`

Stage2 - Model:

Now you post to Model, use `$_POST['name']` to fetch **somebody's name** and write a sql statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tableName 'name' VALUES(:name)"; // Then prepare and bindParam
```

Before you can access database using PDO, your sql statement will be escaped if your gpc is on. That is, **somebody's name** will be **somebody\'s** name now. Then you use PDO to access database. But now in the database **somebody\'s** name is saved, because PDO will not know that the backslash before single quote was added by gpc, instead PDO thinks that you added that backslash before single quote intentionally.

Conclusion: If you use PDO, just turn gpc off.